# the content in the parameter of the main fun in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin language and I want to understand everything in this programming language so.

1- what mean of the `args: Array<String>` in the parameter of the main function ?

2- why compilation error is shown when this line is removed ?

Comment: Same as in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: this line? Which line?

Answer (score 1):

The `main(Array<String>)` function is an entry point of a program. The strings passed are the command-line arguments.

That is, when you run something like

```
$ java myprogram foo bar
```

the `main` function is called with `["foo", "bar"]` as the argument.

This is very much the same thing that Java does, and Java emulates C in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

I keep replacing it with `vararg` everywhere

```
object Application {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(vararg args: String) {
        Micronaut.build()
                .packages("example")
                .mainClass(Application::class.java)
                .start()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens just looks better.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) { 
  println("Hello, world!") 
}
```

In this example, a function named `main` is defined which returns Unit and takes an Array of strings as a parameter.

Comment: No, it won't cause any compilation error. It's perfectly legal to name a function main even though it doesn't have any argument. It just can't be an entry point, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on Java convention, this Kotlin code bellow's the same with Java code.

Kotlin code:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    println("Hello, world!");
}
```

According to @9000 "The main(Array) function is an entry point of a program. The strings passed are the command-line arguments." Each program must have the start entry point. That's just a convention to get the function call parameter.