# How to debug the following error in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception, kotlin-coroutines

Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` at AppsKt.main(Apps.kt:28)

Here is the image link

[Image showing error in the code line 28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLh1G.png)

Comment: please dont post the image but post the code

Comment: @Lucole Adding the block of code would be helpful

Comment: @UmairMubeen noted with thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when you want to access a value in an array with an invalid index. Either the key index is in negative or is greater than or equal to the array size. So if your array is of length 6 the index you pass in to get a value from the array should be between 0 and 5 anything other than that will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you are indexing into the argument array arr[0].  This array is populated by passing an argument either via command-line invocation or Android Studio JVM options.  If you are not passing an argument then this array is empty hence the error.

Whenever acting on data structures coming from user input or other sources of ambiguity, always check for edge cases (null or empty) before trying to access them.

[the content in the parameter of the main fun in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209063/the-content-in-the-parameter-of-the-main-fun-in-kotlin)